# How to open multiple files from `find` output?

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I know I can open multiple files found in a dir like so:

`find -name *.foo -xargs <command> {} \;`

This works, but when trying to open a bunch of textfiles in gedit at the same time, it opens them successively (when one files is closed, the next one is opened).

I would like to open all of those files at the same time.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To act on multiple files at once with `find`, use `+` instead of `\;`:

```
find . -name '*.foo' -exec gedit {} +
```

With zsh, or with bash ≥4 if you put `shopt -s globstar` in your `~/.bashrc`, you can use `**/` to recurse into subdirectories:

```
gedit **/*.foo
```

Zsh also has many [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87) which can replace most uses of `find`.

Comment: could somebody suggest how to run it on Mac OS X?

Comment: @andi solved by myself. But if someone propose someting shorter, or forcing SublimeText to open in seperate tabs, rather than windows, it will be much apriciated.

Comment: @andi This is an issue with SublimeText, you should ask it as a separate thread.

Comment: anyway I think it is about exact bash format, because if I run for example `open -a SublimeText admin.py forms.py` it opens in one window with two tabs.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X bash you can run something like:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.py"); do open -a SublimeText $file; done.
```

One drawback is that it opens in new window of Sublime instead of using new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case you could use

```
find ./ -name \*.foo | xargs gedit
```

Comment: This won't work if the file name contains special characters (whitespace or `\'"`), because `xargs` requires its input to be quoted in a way that `find` doesn't produce. Either use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`, or use the simpler `find … -exec … {} +`.

Comment: Also, though it doesn't apply in this case, `-print0 | xargs -0` has the problem that stdin has been gobbled up, and is no longer attached to the terminal. A problem if you're trying to use a text-mode editor.